# Hibernate: getting error to run this SQL query "alter session enable parallel dml" in Hibernate 5.4.x version

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I have upgraded Hibernate 4.x version to Hibernate 5.4.x version in my application.

I am getting below error while running below SQL query:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
> update/delete query   at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1668)

SQL query:

```
hibernateSession.createSQLQuery("alter session enable parallel dml").executeUpdate();
```

Also failing the parallel running delete query after failing of above dml query.

I have tried using the @Transactional annotation (import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;) on method level and class level but that didnt resolve my issue.

Any suggestion to resolve this error will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added begin transaction in code to resolve the mentioned error.

```
Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
```

This solution worked for me to resolve this error.

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
> update/delete query

But now getting below new error

> ERROR | ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00V
> ORA-12829: Deadlock - itls occupied by siblings at block 3591658 of
> file 175

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your transaction manager integration doesn't work properly then as Hibernate can't join the transaction. Not sure how your Spring configuration looks like, but there must be an issue with that. I guess you also updated Spring? Maybe you are using a now unsupported configuration?

Comment: Hi Christian, Yes I have upgraded Spring 4.x to Spring 5.x version.

I am using the Stateless session to run this DML SQL query.

Comment: Have you seen this in the migration guide? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#data-access-and-transactions

Comment: yes, I have checked that guide now and added the begin Transaction on the hibernate session. But now getting this below error

ERROR | ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00V
ORA-12829: Deadlock - itls occupied by siblings at block 3591658 of file 175